# wrap extra cat5 or cut to length

Tags: cat5e

I have a bunch of runs of cat5 cable that were run thru the house from curious points when remodeling to the basement.  I am going to mount a switch in the rafters in the basement and connect all the cables to them.  Then trunk that switch to my server rack switch elsewhere in the basement.  For most of the cables to make it to the first switch, there will be some extra cable.  Would you leave the slack and wrap it up / Velcro tie it, or cut it to the exact length to make it to the switch.  Considered both and second I'm hesitant as I can't run these cables again so if I cut and later want to run elsewhere may be short.  Thought I would get thoughts.

Thanks

JR

Comment: Leave the length as it is and wrap up the slack as you see fit.

Comment: I hope you used cable ties, _not_ staples like electricians and phone techs use, to run the cable. By the way, Category-5 cable has not been recognized in this century. It was replaced by Category-5e in 1999.

Comment: It is 5e. Sorry for not being specific

Comment: You'll be fine provided the overall length is within the spec.  I have all the cabling wrapped in ladder rack of our datacenter to allow rerun flexibility.

Comment: Make sure also that you take care of the **bend radius** -  "The minimum bend radius for Category 5, 5e, and 6 cable is four times the cable diameter, which is approximately 1 inch. When cabling is bent beyond this specified minimum bend radius, it can cause transmission failures. All pathways must maintain the minimum bend radius wherever the cable makes a bend."